# How to Call javascript function from js file with parameter and return data from tsx file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tsx

I have one js file as `sample.js` which has function like below:

```
function checkLogin(userName, password) {
  var returnvalue = '';
  //logic for login and assign value in returnvalue variable
  return returnvalue;
}
```

I want to call this function from my `.tsx` file how can I do it?

Comment: What is stopping you? Any error messages?

Comment: when I call function from my tsx it shows error "can not find name checkLogin" I tried to do export and import but got same error. may be I missed something in import and export functionality so I want to know how can I do it?

Comment: You need to share that import/export code also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have access to modify the `sample.js`?  If so, try adding `export` in front of your function; ie. **`export`**`function checkLogin(userName, password) {...}`.  Then, import this script in your TSX file using `require` like:

```
var Sample = require("./sample.js");
```

Note this example assumes `sample.js` lives in the same path as your TSX file, but you can modify as needed.

Then, you should be able to access your function by way of calling `Sample.checkLogin(..., ...);` in your TSX.

**Alternative**

If you are able to change make your "sample" script into a TypeScript (TS) file (`sample.ts`), you would still add `export` in front of your function and probably want to add types like `string` to the two function parameters:

```
export function checkLogin(userName: string, password: string) {...}
```

Then, you can use `import` in your TSX file, instead:

```
import * as Sample from "./sample";
```

This also assumes your `sample.ts` lives in the same path as your TSX and would allow you to make calls to `Sample.checkLogin(..., ...);` in your TSX.